# Can GRUB load an ELF file without a multiboot header?

Tags: elf, osdev, grub, multiboot

I have always assumed that this is not the case, however, an [FAQ for a tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Barebones#Frequently_Asked_Questions) I have read recently implies that it is:

> ## Why the multiboot header? Wouldn't a pure ELF file be loadable by GRUB anyway?
>
> GRUB is capable of loading a variety of formats. However, in this tutorial we are creating a Multiboot compliant kernel that could be loaded by any other compliant bootloader. To achieve this, the multiboot header is mandatory.

I tried to Google it immediately, without any useful results. So: Does GRUB support loading ELF files without a multiboot header?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17921401/138792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the answer is yes. But only in the form of GRUB loadable modules.

See also [Grub bootloader with shared library support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396711/grub-bootloader-with-shared-library-support/25492131#25492131).