# Enable the GRUB boot loader

Tags: osdev

I made my kernel for my operating system. I want to boot the kernel with the GRUB boot loader. How do I link my `.bin` file created by the `i686-elf-gcc` using the `-T` parameter with GRUB? Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this question is on-topic here. It feels more like something that will better fly on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but check their help center first.

Comment: If your kernel/BIN needs to be in real mode to begin with you'd need to use the `chainloader`option in GRUB. The easiest way of doing that is creating a bootable ISO image. There is an example of that in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32920643/3857942

Comment: An example of creating a multiboot compliant kernel that runs in protected mode and can be loaded directly with GRUB can be found in Ciro Santilli's bare metal github repository https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/d1f11492c2d2828c9c713d75b6f173da955aafc3/multiboot/hello-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the GRUB file, you can visit [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) link. It contains info about how to link your assembly and c kernel file and how to create a GRUB configuration file to create a bootable ISO file with the GRUB bootloader on it. The only thing about that tutorial is it expects you to have the [gcc cross-compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) setup or the commands will not all work.